Time series classification, using lagged data, and exogenous time series variables for exploratory features
I have the following pandas dataframe
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({
    'region': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
    'week': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
    'rain': [1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    'clouds': [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]
})

region  week    rain    clouds
0   1   1   1   1
1   1   2   1   1
2   1   3   0   0
3   1   4   1   0
4   2   1   1   0
5   2   2   1   0
6   2   3   1   1
7   2   4   1   0
8   3   1   1   1
9   3   2   0   0
10  3   3   0   0
11  3   4   0   0

which indicates at a specific region, at a specific week, if it rained, considering if there clouds at that region at that week.
In my toy example, I would like to be able to predict if it will rain at week n, taking into account if it rained the previous weeks and also if there were clouds the previous weeks.
How could I achieve that ? What would be an appropriate model for this type of problems ?

this is really the wrong forum for this type of question.  you should ask in the cross-validated (stats) stack exchange.  SO is for issues with programming.

I understand it is not a "programming" question, though programming is not only coding, is solution outline as well, no ?

It is not a bad question, just the wrong forum.  Please try asking in https://stats.stackexchange.com/
